# How to bind to ctrl+x in bash?

Tags: bash

I appear to be using GNU bash, version 4.4.12, though it's possible my organization has modified it from HEAD. I'm trying to bind ctrl+x:

```
$ bind -x '"\C-t": "echo testing"'
<I press ctrl+t>
testing
$ bind -x '"\C-x": "echo testing"'
<I press ctrl+x>
-bash: bash_execute_unix_command: cannot find keymap for command
```

EDIT: Just realized I can bind `\C-x\C-x` (or any other combo that starts with `\C-x`. So it seems that ctrl+x is recognized but somehow required to be part of a longer sequence. I know there are lots of default sequences starting with ctrl+x, and I even tried unbinding all of them to see if it would help (it did not).

Comment: Does it happen under `bash --noprofile` (or also `--norc`) ?

Comment: Read `man bash` and search for "Readline Key Bindings".

Comment: @thrig Yes, it still happens in both those cases. But, I found one new interesting detail and edited it into the OP.

Comment: Looks like there is a keymap `emacs-ctlx` and `C-x` is permanently bound to that, so it can be a prefix char for 2 character bindings. You could move to vi mode, but that will change lots of other bindings.

Comment: @meuh Interestingly, if I [specify a keymap in my bind command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), **any** keymap, then the error message goes away, and instead the screen clears after pressing ctrl+x. Ironically, clearing the screen is the action I originally wanted a binding for. So in a way that solves my issue. But not really because (a) the mystery still remains and (b) there is a small delay with this binding, and I'd rather it be instantaneous which I can do if I can truly change the binding action (I suspect it's calling `reset` now, which is slow.